# How to do a linear search of two vectors in c++?

Tags: c++

UPDATE:
My code works, there was something wrong outside of this code.

I have two vectors containing objects of class Books.  One vector has new books and another vector contains requested books. I am trying to create a linear search function that counts the number of matching books between the two vectors.

Here is my linear search function:

```
int linear(vector<Books> New, vector<Books> Requested){
  int matches = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < New.size(); i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < Requested.size(); j++){
      if (New[i].convstr() == Requested[j].convstr())
        matches++;
    }
  }
  cout << matches << endl;
}
```

I also have a convstr() function to convert the objects into a string to compare them (in the class Books it is public):

```
string Books::convstr(){
  string strisbn;
  strisbn = to_string(isbn);
  return strisbn + language + type;
}
```

Whenever I enter the two vectors and try to print the number of matches it always prints zero even if there is a match.

Comment: linear imply `O(n)`, your is `O(n²)`. Can be done in `O(n log n)` with [std::set_intersection](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) after sorting input.

Comment: *"I also have a `convstr()` function to convert the objects into a string"*. To `std::string`, right? Not `const char*`.

Comment: @Jarod42 yes, convstr() converts it into std::string not const char*

Comment: Nothing really wrong with what you show, so error must be with what you don't show. Show `convstr()`

Comment: Are you sure your two inputs are non-empty?

Comment: @acraig5075 I added convstr() it converts the isbn numbers of the books to a string and adds the type and language of the book (already strings) into one string.

Comment: @acraig5075 yes, I run two .txt files through and they are both non-empty

Comment: @Christina Do you mean the files are non-empty? I mean are `New` and `Requested` non-empty? Print out their sizes as a requirement check.

Comment: @Jarod42 why don't you make your comment an answer? Your solution is probably the most elegant way to go...

Comment: @andreee: We lack of MCVE to spot OP's issue. so not sure providing mu method will solve OP's issue.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jarod42 said you can use `std::set_intersection` to solve this problem in `O(n log n)`. This snippet is doing the job, if the arrays are sorted.

```
#include <algorithm>

template <typename T>
T getCommonItems(T &container_0, T &container_1) {
    T cache;
    cache.reserve(std::min(container_0.size(), container_1.size()));
    std::set_intersection(container_0.begin(), container_0.end(), container_1.begin(), container_1.end(),
                          std::back_inserter(cache));
    return cache;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters the function should be declared at least like

```
size_t linear( const vector<Books> &New, const vector<Books> &Requested );
```

Otherwise redundant copies of the vectors will be created.

Also supposing that the vectors do not contain duplicated books the second loop can be shortened.

As for your function implementation then you forgot to return the value of the variable `matches`.

The function can be defined the following way

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

//...

size_t linear( const vector<Books> &New, const vector<Books> &Requested )
{
    size_t matches = 0;

    for ( const auto &book : New )
    {
        if ( std::find_if( std::begin( Requested ), std::end( Requested ), 
                           [&book]( const auto &item ) { return book.convstr() == item.convstr(); } ) != std::end( Requested ) )
        {
            ++matches; 
        }
    }

    return matches;
}
```

Pay attention to that the member function convstr shall be declared with the qualifier `const`. For example

```
bool convstr() const;
```

Comment: This is an excellent code review, but doesn't answer why in @Christina's case `matches` is zero. imo and unless I'm missing something the question is unanswerable without more info.

Comment: @acraig5075 There is written in the answer what is the problem.:)